# Regex is not working in C

Tags: regex, posix

I am using regex when I use it on shell it works but not inside the C program.

Any thoughts please?

```
echo "abc:1234567890@werty.wer.sdfg.net" | grep -E "(\babc\b|\bdef\b):[0-9]{10}@([A-Za-z0-9].*)"   //shell

reti = regcomp(&regex,"(\babc\b|\bdef\b):[0-9]{10}@([A-Za-z0-9].*)", 0); //c program
```

Comment: `grep -E` uses ERE syntax (I think it is close to ERE, with some enhancements). Pass `REG_EXTENDED` flag to the `regcomp`. Still, I am not sure `\b` is supported by `regex.h`.

Comment: Your C version uses single backslashes inside a C string. That will not work, as those backslashes are not passed on into your regex library. (Which is?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -E` uses some enhanced ERE syntax meaning that the `{n,m}` quantifier braces (and also `(` and `)`) do not have to be escaped (not the case in BRE regex).

You need to pass `REG_EXTENDED` flag to the `regcomp`, and also, since you can't use a word boundary, replace the first `\b` with `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])` "equivalent". You need no trailing `\b` since there is a `:` in the pattern right after:

```
const char *str_regex = "(^|[^[:alnum:]_])(abc|def):[0-9]{10}@([A-Za-z0-9].*)";
```

The `(^|[^[:alnum:]_])` part matches either the start of the string (`^`) or (`|`) a char other than alphanumeric or an underscore.

Full [C demo](https://ideone.com/FFtpur):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (void)
{
  int match;
  int err;
  regex_t preg;
  regmatch_t pmatch[4];
  size_t nmatch = 4;
  const char *str_request = "abc:1234567890@werty.wer.sdfg.net";

  const char *str_regex = "(^|[^[:alnum:]_])(abc|def):[0-9]{10}@([A-Za-z0-9].*)";
  err = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED);
  if (err == 0)
    {
      match = regexec(&preg, str_request, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
      nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
      regfree(&preg);
      if (match == 0)
        {
          printf("\"%.*s\"\n", pmatch[2].rm_eo - pmatch[2].rm_so, &str_request[pmatch[2].rm_so]);
          printf("\"%.*s\"\n", pmatch[3].rm_eo - pmatch[3].rm_so, &str_request[pmatch[3].rm_so]);
        }
      else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
        {
          printf("unmatch\n");
        }
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Plus 1. Thanks a lot Wiktor Stribiżew . It helped me a lot. Sincerely.

Comment: Great. Just mind that `regmatch_t pmatch[4]` and `size_t nmatch = 4` depend on the number of capturing groups defined in the pattern: `4` = 1 + amount of `(...)` *capturing* groups.

Answer (score 1):

*Word Boundary Reference*

[General](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html)
[POSIX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html#posix)

From the above links it appears POSIX supports it's own word boundary construct.
Note that these constructs `[[:<:]]`, `[[:>:]]` are *not* classes.

Given that, and using ERE as opposed to BRE, you should be able to do this -

`reti = regcomp(&regex,"[[:<:]](abc|def)[[:>:]]:[0-9]{10}@([A-Za-z0-9].*)", REG_EXTENDED);`

or, since between `[cf]` and `:` is a natural word boundary, it can be reduced to

`reti = regcomp(&regex,"[[:<:]](abc|def):[0-9]{10}@([A-Za-z0-9].*)", REG_EXTENDED);`

I haven't tested this but it probably works.
And given it's actually *unclear* as to what this does internally, it might be better to
stick with this syntax.

Some engines, like *Boost* which have the POSIX option, customize the syntax to `\<` and `\>`